# set a fragment dynamically

Tags: java, android, layout, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivty where its layout is composed by a LinearLayout with some buttons at the half-left, and a empty container FrameLayout at the half-right where I want to insert other activities (Maybe they should be fragments instead of activities).

Depending the button I touch, it will call one activity/fragment and this will be displayed on the container framelayout.

For this I have:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout     

<!-- Buttons containing layout -->    
<LinearLayout 

    <Button
        ... />
    ...

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Blank space which will contain other activities -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activitycontent"
    ...>    
</FrameLayout>
```

This is a example of a activity/frament to set dinamically on the container framelayout:

**Content1.java**

```
public class Content1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**Inflate the layout for this fragment*/
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
```

**So, the question is**:  *How can I define the framelayout as a container for content1 activity/frament, and how I set it? (Remembering that I call to the activty/fragment when I touch the button)*

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. check the topic programatically adding fragment to viewgroup

Comment: Check also documentation about multi pane http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On button click

```
Content1 fragment = new Content1();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activitycontent, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Programmatically add the fragment to an existing `ViewGroup`(container).
At any time while your activity is running, you can add fragments to your activity layout. You simply need to specify a `ViewGroup` in which to place the fragment.

Comment: This will go in the Main.java true? Do I have to set something on the Content1.java?

Comment: @masmic_87 just try as suggested your fragment looks ok

Comment: @masmic_87 yes it goes in Main.java and  do you have a single fragment or or multiple fragments.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it in a while. I have about 5 activities/fragments that I call with each button, thats why I need a container to set fragments dynamically

Comment: you can use replace to replace the container with other fragments and add the fragment to backstack `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`. if you don't add it to back stack it will be destroyed and you can't navigate back to it

Comment: could you write an example of how to do it? I don't know how to use that function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40567/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-masmic-87)

Answer (score 0):

To load the fragment do

```
public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack)
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fragmentManager == null)
    {
        Log.e("switchContent", "Fragment manager is null, exiting");
        return;
    }
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if(fragmentTransaction == null)
    {
        Log.e("switchContent", "Fragment transaction is null, exiting");
        return;
    }

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activitycontent, fragment);
    if(addToBackStack)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

on click of the button call this method as

```
switchContent(new Content1(), false);
```

or

```
switchContent(new Content1(), true); // if want this fragment to be added in stack
```